# Is there a maven command to run a docker application?

Tags: java, maven, docker

To begin with, I am trying to learn the basic concepts of Docker and its basic commands. What I came across so far is that to run a Docker image I have to use `$docker run .....` command to start the Docker container and get the application running.

What I want to ask, and couldn't find the answer to, is that, is there a way to run the Docker application directly using maven command like we have to build the Docker image like `$mvn clean install docker:build`

Thanks and advance

Comment: Yes, there is https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Comment: In addition to the spotify's docker maven plugin, there's https://dmp.fabric8.io/ this as well

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, @AdamSiemion, that plugin doesn't have the `docker run...` equivalent goal available in it.

Comment: @AnilCherukuri I can see the run goal available in it but have not tried yet. Will put a comment here once I get to try it out.